# removing known outliers from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In a pandas dataframe subsets (here my outliers) should be removed:

example:

```
df = data[~(data.outlier1 == 1)]
```

But my dataframe has multiple outlier rows.

Is there something like:

```
 df = data[~((data.outlier1 == 1) or (data.outlier2 == 1) or (data.outlier3 == 1))]
```

The idea is to subtract all outliers (encoded in different rows) at the same time.

Comment: Sorry are you after `df = data[~((data.outlier1 == 1) | (data.outlier2 == 1) | (data.outlier3 == 1))]`?

Comment: Yes. thanks. I know this is probably basic knowledge, but I am not that experienced with python or pandas. Also, I think short question with comprehensive answers are useful for other unexperienced users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC then you just need to use the bitwise or operator `|` to test for multiple conditions:

```
df = data[~((data.outlier1 == 1) | (data.outlier2 == 1) | (data.outlier3 == 1))]
```

The reason is because you are comparing arrays with a scalar so you should use the bitwise `|` operator rather than `or`

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to truncate outliers by winsorizing. In the example below, each column will be capped and floored at the 5th and 95th percentile, without losing any rows:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import mstats
%matplotlib inline

test_data = pd.Series(range(30))
test_data.plot()
```

[image: Original data]

```
# Truncate values to the 5th and 95th percentiles
transformed_test_data = pd.Series(mstats.winsorize(test_data, limits=[0.05, 0.05])) 
transformed_test_data.plot()
```

[image: Winsorized data]